# XSL: How to print an iterated node in for-each

Tags: xslt, xpath

xml:

```
<skills>
  <skill>PHP</skill>
  <skill>CSS</skill>
  <skill>HTML</skill>
  <skill>XML</skill>
</skills>
```

XSL:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="skills/skill">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="[what should be xpath here]" /></li
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Here what should be the xpath to print each skill?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a solution with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the values of skill tags as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="skills/skill">
<li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: to begin with you can accept the answer as correct and gain some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**: `.`

The `.` abbreviation is equivalent to `self::node()` and means: *the current node*.

`<xsl:value-of select="someNode"/>`

outputs the string value of the node, which in your case is the value of only text node of the `skills/skill` node that is currently selected by the `<xsl:for-each>` instruction.